# How do I print a hash in the same order the elements were added?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to use a hash in a LIFO or FIFO way? How can I make sure that the hash is printed in the same order the elements where added?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print "content-type: text/html \n\n";

# BEGINNING HASH
%coins = ( "Quarter" , .25,
          "Dime" ,    .10,
          "Nickel",   .05 );
# PRINT THE OLD HASH
while (($key, $value) = each(%coins)){
    print $key.", ".$value."<br />";
}

# ADD NEW ELEMENT PAIRS
$coins{Penny} = .01;
$coins{HalfDollar} = .50;

# PRINT THE NEW HASH
print "<br />";
while (($key, $value) = each(%coins)){
     print $key.", ".$value."<br />";
}
```

This gives

```
Nickel, 0.05
Dime, 0.1
Quarter, 0.25

Nickel, 0.05
Dime, 0.1
HalfDollar, 0.5
Penny, 0.01
Quarter, 0.25
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can either keep a separate array of the hash keys, so that you can write

```
my @coins = qw/ Quarter Dime Nickel Penny HalfDollar /;

for my $key (@coins) {
  print "$key, $coins{$key}<br />\n";
}
```

or you can install and use the [`Tie::IxHash`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aIxHash) module, which will keep the hash elements in the order they were inserted, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::IxHash;
tie my %coins, 'Tie::IxHash';

print "content-type: text/html \n\n";

%coins = (
  Quarter => 0.25,
  Dime    => 0.10,
  Nickel  => 0.05,
);

while (my ($key, $value) = each %coins){
    print "$key, $value<br />\n";
}

$coins{Penny} = .01;
$coins{HalfDollar} = .50;

print "<br />\n";
while (my ($key, $value) = each(%coins)){
     print "$key, $value<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

default hashes don't  preserve order - that's the very nature of hashes. You could use a module like [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aIxHash) to preserve the order the items were added.

Answer (score -1):

I have come up with a solution without any need of using  [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aIxHash).

The approach is to add a character/number before the `key` of the hash.

This will allow us to get the order in which we pushed keys in the hash when  `keys` will be `sort`ed.

Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/perl/bin -w    
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ();

my @keys = qw(one two three);
my $count = 0;

for(my $i=0; $i<scalar(@keys); $i++) {
    $hash{ chr($count) . $keys[$i] } = 1;
    $count++;
}

foreach my $key (sort { ord $a <=> ord $b } keys(%hash) ) {
    print substr($key, 1) . " => " . $hash{$key}. "\n";
}
```

Comment: This will only work for up to ten elements! You could change this to MAXINT elements by encoding the count as a pseudo-codepoint. Change to `$hash{ chr($count) . $keys[$i] }`, `sort { ord $a <=> ord $b }`. The `ord` function will return the ord of the first char if a string with length > 1 is given.

Comment: Made the changes. Thanks @amon.